# How to see uploaded file on cloud service of azure?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have successfully deployed my service to the azure cloud services and its working great. But I am having one problem, I have a logging layer in my service which logs activities and error to the log files. But now when I have deployed my service to azure cloud services I am unable to access the log files, since I made the package file for deploying it to azure. Can somebody tell me how to access those logs file.

Comment: Does this help? http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-monitor/#howtoconfigdiagnostics

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure Diagnostics - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433048.aspx.

There is also a couple short 5 minute videos that shows how to set it up and use it - http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/DIY-Windows-Azure-Troubleshooting/Enabling-WAD and http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/DIY-Windows-Azure-Troubleshooting/WAD-Intro.